# How to prevent extra query for this field in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models like this:

```
class City(models.Model):
    some_field = models.ForeignKey('self')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Author(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    # other fields

    def get_some_field(self):
        return self.city.some_field
    
    some_field = cached_property(get_some_field, name='some_field')
```

I fetch Author queryset something like this:

```
author_qs = Author.objects.filter(**some_filter).select_related('city')
```

Now after fetching the queryset, I do something like this:

```
city_name = author_qs.some_field.name
```

But this line is querying the database again for City model. How can I prevent this extra query, and get city_name with previous query only.

P.S. I cannot directly get `author_qs.city.name`. I require it to call from `some_field` only

Comment: try `author_qs = Author.objects.filter(**some_filter).select_related('city__some_field')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
author_qs = Author.objects.filter(**some_filter).select_related('city__some_field')
```